# upload a image in multiple directories using PluploadPlugin

Tags: php, jquery

I have implemented the PluploadPlugin plugin for multiple file upload using drag and drop now i want to upload these images into different different directories but there are only these files uploaded into on directory either first directory or last directory so please can any one help me what can i do for this 
please give me solution it's very important for me 
thanks

Comment: we can user copy() function for this

Answer (score 0):

After searching I found a function in php which is use to copy the uploaded files from uploaded directory (these files uploaded into this) to many other directories which is define when files uploaded
this function is [copy()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function  please visit this